# Date type for Xero journal date

Tags: python, json, xero-api

Below is a  output of the API call for the journal endpoint in Xero developing.
[Xero](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/journals#GET) (See the jason output)

```
JournalNumber;JournalDate
344;/Date(1590019200000+0000)/
```

Does anyone know what is the format of this journal date and is there anyway I can convert this to `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: It's in the doc here: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/requests-and-responses - it's a Unix timestamp but in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah this is the MS date format, just an epoch date prefixed with `Date` - It is legacy on a few of the xero API endpoints. All the SDK's should handle this deserialization for you but easily converted by plucking out the timestamp.

Pretty sure the python SDK handles this for you: https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-python/blob/d0473ba91099de3464b3dffa377df5a11ad95afc/xero_python/api_client/deserializer.py#L145

Comment: Does not handle it for me with the latest sdk, at least not when I serialize the model.